# Eclipse doesn't recognize android SDK

Tags: android

I set android SDK on centos(linux)
[image]
but then I get 
[image]
when I'm trying to get to Android SDK and AVD Manager in Window menu.
Why?? 
I have the latest ADT plugin, I've tried android_sdk revision 13 and 12, both didn't work. WHY?

Comment: let's check you're looking at the right place. In my eclipse I point it to `/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/r12`. If I do an `ls` on this directory, I have the following `README, bin, extras, platforms, temp, add-ons, docs, platform-tools, samples, tools`

Comment: Have you performed Step 4 from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html?

Comment: I'm trying to perform step 4 but I can't because of this error

Comment: I think you can try in Eclipse > Help > Check for updates.  And it should try to automatically update your android sdk/ADT?  Otherwise you can try running the sdk/avd manager manually via the `android` executable in either the `tools` or `platform-tools` folder.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows "X.X" OS, being any variant of the operating system, I had issues such as yours. My best solution short of using Virtual Box / VMWare to run a Linux OS would be to make a guest account with the Lowest Potential Privileges, (Non-Admin, read write only, etc.) and only the account for Development. It is the same basic rule of thumb I always use on Linux, or OS X because you can't screw the environment up. After that, I would try and download everything over. (I am sorry if you do not have a good download speed, but from experience, believe me even a 220/kbps Download speed is a minor inconvenience once you have a Dev. Account set up.) I hope this